# get mutliple selected VALUES from SELECT OPTIONS in jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, servlet-3.0

Firstly, please check if the way I'm populating the select options in the right way.
Secondly, please provide method to get the multiple selected options onto servlet.
I am using object values to populate options by using expression language.

I have used

```
String[] userChoosenSeatIds =request.getParameterValues("getSelectedSeat");
```

the above code in servlet to fetch the selected option values in jsp.
Also on executing this code, it gave me NullPointerException.

Below is my jsp code:

```
  <form method="post" action="chosenSeats.do">
  <table width="300" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><label> Select the Seat(s)</label>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <select name="getSelectedSeat" size="7" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
            <core:forEach items="${ requestScope.seatList }" var="seat">
                <option value="${seat.seatId  }">${ seat.seatRow } ${seat.seatNumber }</option>
            </core:forEach>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Book" value="Book" tabindex="2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
   </form>
```

**I need to get the selected values into a list.**

Comment: any help appreciated!

Comment: Does your `select box` with values show in browser?

Comment: yes! it does and also i can select multiple values which are displayed. but as i click submit button it gives me nullpointerException in servlet part. Not fetching those values

Comment: @Swati is there any way around or alternative?

Comment: thank you it is working now ! I figured it out.